# Mongo $text search not finding the or your

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb `$text` index and I noticed that it's not finding simple words like 'the' or 'your'.  Is there a way to enable this? Can't seem to find anything.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `language` to "none" to disable stop-words, stemming etc completely: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Custom stop-words feature is in the backlog:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10062.