# Text Search not finding documents

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run a simple text search but the hits returned are not what I would expect.

```
db.inventory.createIndex({item: "text"})

db.inventory.insertOne({ item: "us"})
db.inventory.insertOne({ item: "me"})
db.inventory.insertOne({ item: "you"})

db.inventory.find( { $text: { $search: "us" } } ) // Found the document
db.inventory.find( { $text: { $search: "me" } } ) // Nothing Found
db.inventory.find( { $text: { $search: "you" } } ) // Nothing Found
```

Setting language to none (per [Mongo $text search not finding the or your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759077/mongo-text-search-not-finding-the-or-your)) didn't change the behavior

Comment: Sorry, I just read your last comment. Are you sure that didn't help. I have done just that now and setting the language to `none` does fix the issue. All searches return results with that. -> ```db.inventory.createIndex(
   { item : "text" },
   { default_language: "none" }
)``` 

Which version of mongo are you using. I believe the `language` keyword may have changed?

Comment: You're right.  I must've messed something up before because setting up the index like you proposed worked.

For more clarification, me and us are both stop words so are not indexed.  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt

Comment: glad to hear it :)

Comment: When I tried setting language, it was just for the query, not the index.  That was the problem.